# C# app throws access denied error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I have .net app in which there is function for Database backup and restore. When I installed this program using Setup & Deployment project I am unable to make back up from my app. It give me **Operating System error 5(Access denied)**. I have installed this on Windows & ultimate OS on default location (C:\Program Files\My Company\My Software). But when I installed this on "**C:\MySoftware**" location it is working perfectly, no error. What could be the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Altering files under the Program Files folder requires elevated rights. Does your backup/restore application have a manifest for elevating rights to the necessary level? If not, [this Q&A has some info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3511174/access-to-program-files-folder-needed).