# Folder created by application stored in virtual store winForm

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-7, .net-4.0

I have created setup for my windows form application . My OS is Windows7

On load of first form I have created folder with below code

```
 bool IsExists = System.IO.Directory.Exists("Orders");
                if (!IsExists)
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("Orders");
```

But when i install setup project on machine this folder is created at following path.

```
  C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files\MySetup
```

Is there any workaround so that folders i create is stored on

```
 C:\Program Files\MySetup
```

Anything related to permission or rights to user?

Any Solutions?

Comment: I don't think this would be a good idea, since users generally don't have sufficient privileges to create subfolders in Program files.

Comment: thanx @MarkoJuvančič  But i am logged in as admin only

Comment: What if you create folder Orders on a fixed location (c:\VirtualStore\orders) and you don't to have to worry about setup location? 
What is your setup made with (ClickOnce or sth else)

Answer (score 1):

Look:

- To get specific related folder, use [Environment.SpecialFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
- This path can be transformed to `String` by using [Environment.GetFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
  For example:

  ```
  String programFilesPath = 
      Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles);
  ```
- Getting authorized [access to Program Files is discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3511174/access-to-program-files-folder-needed)